# Prove the linear dependence of cosx, cos(x+1), cos(x-1)

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, trigonometry

I'm struggling to prove the linear dependence of the functions cos(x), cos(x+1), and cos(x-1). Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: what is $\cos(x+1)+\cos(x-1)$?

Comment: cosxcos1-sinxsin1 and cosxcos1 + sinxsin1. I tried everything I know I just feel like i'm missing something. What method would you use? Is computing the wronskian the easiest?

Comment: @RT5754 The answer has already been put on the table: Since $\cos(x+1)+\cos(x-1)=2\cos(1)\cos(x)=const\cdot\cos(x)$. You don’t need to compute a Wronskian determinant here.

Comment: @RT5754 Don’t forget the “+”!

Comment: Thank you! Facepalm moment